# change mousemove cursor type

Tags: jquery, mousemove

Hi i am using the following code as a tooltip which follows the mouse

```
$("#main").mousemove(function(e) { 
  $('ms-slide-info').css('cursor', 'url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mouse-icon-small.png"), auto');
  $('.ms-slide-info ').css('left', e.pageX + 10).css('top', e.pageY + 5).css('display', 'block');
});
```

However whilst the tooltip works fine and follows the mouse, it uses the 'grab' css property for the 'cursor' and no matter what i try i cannot seem to change this to another cursor type.

view the page here: http://emgs.scrappydog.co.uk/

any help greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: You can  enhance your code in this way:-`$("#main").mousemove(function(e) { 
 $('ms-slide-info').css({'cursor':'url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mouse-icon-small.png"), auto','left':e.pageX + 10,'top':e.pageY + 5,'display':'block'});
});`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using a slider component, which internally uses `ms-grab-cursor` and `ms-grabbing-cursor` classes. And that's the reason why your mouse pointer appears as grabbing.

You may want to override these settings:

```
.ms-grab-cursor, .ms-grabbing-cursor {
  cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by adding this css:

```
.ms-slide-bgcont, .ms-slide-bgcont:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need 2 task, detect mouse moving and dragging. here answer for changing cursor on mouse move

```
var timeout;
document.onmousemove = function () {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    // reset to default cursor if not moving
    jQuery('.ms-view').css('cursor', 'url("wp-content/plugins/masterslider/public/assets/css/common/grab.png"), move');
  }, 1000);
}
jQuery('#main').mousemove(function (e) {
  jQuery('.ms-view').css('cursor', 'url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mouse-icon-small.png"), auto');
  jQuery('.ms-slide-info').css('left', e.pageX + 10).css('top', e.pageY + 5).css('display', 'block');
});
```